# Named Scope/filter question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, named

Sorry, I am still a little green with Ruby on Rails to say the least so I'd appreciate even being guided in the same direction.

So... I have three DB tables, let's call them people, jobs and hats.
I have a scope that returns only people that do certain jobs:

```
named_scope :emergency_workers, :include => :job, :conditions => {'jobs.name' => 'Police', 'jobs.name' => 'Fire','jobs.name' => 'paramedic'}
```

I have a scope that returns only people that wear a hat:

```
named_scope :hat_wearers, :include => :job, :joins => :hat, :conditions => ["hats.name IS NOT ?", nil]
```

My question is, how do I define a scope that says "show me only people that wear a hat (as above) unless they do this particular job, say farmer". So, my code would return all the hat wearers and all the farmers.

Not sure if that makes even a lick of sense but I'd be very grateful for guidance...

Comment: Are you using Rails 3? This looks like Rails 2 syntax.

Comment: So what is the Rails 3 syntax? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how to construct that as a single query, but using Rails 3 syntax you could specify the given scopes then create a method that returns the unique results from two scoped finds:

```
class People < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  scope :emergency_workers, joins(:jobs).where('jobs.name IN (?)',['Police','Fire','Paramedic'])
  scope :hat_wearers, joins(:hats).where('hats.name IS NOT ?', nil)
  scope :farmers, joins(:jobs).where('jobs.name= ?', 'farmer')
  ...

  def hats_and_farmers
    result = self.class.hat_wearers + self.class.farmers
    result.uniq
  end
  ...
end
```

**EDIT:**

I don't know how to write the SQL to do a find based on three tables, but if you do (per your comment) just write this:

```
People.find_by_sql('Your custom from scratch query goes here.')
```

See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#finding-by-sql

All that calling this from a model does is tell Rails what kind of object you're expecting the query to return so that it can instantiate them as objects ready for you to use. No SQL is pre-written for you that way.

Comment: See edits above -- if you know how to write it in raw SQL you can always just use `.find_by_sql()`

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using two separate named scopes and chaining them together. You could use your existing `hat_wearers` scope and also define a scope that takes the name of the job to exclude:

```
named_scope :hat_wearers, :joins => :hat, :conditions => ["hats.name IS NOT ?", nil]
named_scope :without_worker, lambda{|j| :joins  => :job, :conditions => ['jobs.name != ?', j]}
```

Now you can chain them together and call `person.hat_wearers.without_worker('farmer')` as well as use the scopes individually.

A note of warning: depending on the version of Rails you are using, chaining scopes with :joins can get tricky. Several people have written about it on the web and asked about it on this site, so check that out if you get stuck.

Comment: If you chain the scopes, is it additive? So how would I say show me hat wearers *and* farmers (i.e. where hats.name IS NOT ? OR jobs.name = 'farmer'). Sooo wish I was allowed to write a line of SQL right now.

Comment: You are allowed to write SQL. Just write People.find_by_sql(*your completely custom SQL query here*)